# Redis java.util.NoSuchElementException: Pool exhausted

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, redis-cluster

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Pool exhausted - Unable to get key(xxx), Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Pool exhausted
```

I got this error when I am trying to get the key from cluster Redis using `BoundedAsyncPool`,

```
private Integer maxTotal = 20;
private Integer maxIdle  = 20;
private Integer minIdle = 10 ;
```

And this is my code :

```
@Override
public Object get(String key, Class<?> clazz) {
    CompletableFuture<String> getResult = pool.acquire().thenCompose(connection -> {
        connection.setReadFrom(ReadFrom.REPLICA);
        RedisAdvancedClusterAsyncCommands<String, String> async = connection.async();
        return async.get(key).whenComplete((s, throwable) -> pool.release(connection));
    });
    try {
        String value = getResult.get();
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
            return null;
        }
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(value, clazz);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e, String.format("Unable to get key(%s), Exception: %s", key, e.getMessage()));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the whole stracktrace?

Comment: I don't seem to see a `pool.closeAsync()` is used to close the poll opened, their [doc as that](https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/#connection-pooling.asynchronous.connection-pool-support:~:text=Basic%20usage,-RedisClient%20client%20%3D%20RedisClient.create()%3B)